# How to properly override Ext.data.Connection in Extjs4?

Tags: extjs4

I am trying to create a custom function that would be called every time the server sends a response. I can successfully do this in Extjs3 using the following code:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.Connection, { 
    handleResponse : function( response ) {
        console.log('function call');
    }
});
```

I would like to know what would I need to change in order for this code to work in Extjs 4.2.0?

Thanks, Y_Y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking inside Extjs 4.2.0 library file Connection.js I noticed there was no 'handleResponse' function declared as in Extjs 3.2.1 was declared. Instead, Extjs 4.2.0 has a 'onComplete' function. Overriding this function gave me the ability to handle few things before 'requestcomplete' similar to overriding 'handleResponse'.

Comment: Looks like you figured it out before I could reply to your comment. Ideally, you'd send a response with an error code and include your "isError" message in the error body. But you can also override `onComplete` just as you suggested.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually need to override or extend anything. The documentation for [`Ext.data.Connection`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.data.Connection) shows that it fires three events. Two of them are `requestcomplete` which fires when a request succeeds, and `requestexception` which fires when a request fails.

Now, refer to the documentation for [`Ext.util.Observable.observe`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/api/Ext.util.Observable-static-method-observe) which demonstrates how to capture all the events for a given class. Example:

```
Ext.util.Observable.observe(Ext.data.Connection, {
    requestcomplete: function(conn, response, options){
        // Do stuff on success
    },
    requestexception: function(conn, response, options){
        // Do stuff on failure
    }
});
```

That's how you get all completion events for all `Ext.Ajax` requests. Internally, the `observe` method uses the `capture` method so you'll have to call `releaseCapture` on your class when cleaning up.

Comment: I agree with your answer however., I was passing a response with an 'isError' in the overriden handleResponse funtion. Doing that I was able to identify if my custom responses contained errors and then call fireEvent('requestcomplete/requestexception') depending in 'isError'. Your way forces me to do my logic inside 'requestcomplete' and fire 'requestexception' after reading 'isError' off the response parameter... Is that the way it should be? Or is there an event I can use that can read the response before firing 'requestcomplete' or 'requestexception'?